# How to conditional create resource in Terraform based on a string variable

Tags: terraform

While it is common to create a resource based on a boolean variable conditionally, I'm looking for a way to conditionally generate the resource base on the string in the variable.

For example, I am creating the variable `day = Sunday`; now, if the variable is *not* Sunday, Terraform will create the resource; else - nothing will get created.

Is there a way in TF to achieve that?

Comment: Terraform manages resources, and does not "create or not create". You will probably need to approach this differently, or else the end result will not be what you want.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, however, if I'm working with a boolean variable, TF will create/not create the resource: 

resource "some_resource" {
count = var.enable_autoscaling ? 1 : 0
...
}

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you just replace the `boolean` condition with `string` condition?

For example::

```
variable "day" {
  type        = string
  default     = "Sunday"
  description = "Defaults to Sunday. We only create resource when it's not Sunday"
}
```

Then the resource, could be created when it's not Sunday::

```
resource "some_resource" { 
  count = var.day != "Sunday" ? 1 : 0 
  ... 
}
```

If this is not you are expecting, then my understanding is incorrect. Spare me for that..