# Dynamically run terraform block based on input variable value

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform

The Problem:

AWS doesn't support enhanced monitoring for t3.small instances which is what we use for smaller deployments of RDS but does on larger instance sizes for RDS. We want to disable it in Terraform when the instance class is t3.

Looking at the terraform resource docs: https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/db_instance seems like you don't specify interval and role when you don't want to enable enhanced monitoring.

I'm trying to dynamically execute the resource block based on what the monitoring interval is set to. Thus, when its set to 0 run the block without monitoring role arn and when its set to anything other than 0 run the block where it is set.

however I'm getting an error:

```
╷
│ Error: Missing newline after argument
│ 
│ On main.tf line 68: An argument definition must end with a newline.
╵

Error: Terraform exited with code 1.
Error: Process completed with exit code 1.
```

I was following the following stack post: [How to conditional create resource in Terraform based on a string variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72087946/how-to-conditional-create-resource-in-terraform-based-on-a-string-variable)

but it doesn't seem to work with the above error.

Here is my terraform code:

```
    resource "aws_rds_cluster_instance" "cluster_instances" {
  count                            = var.monitoring_interval != "0" ? var.cluster_instance_count : 0
  identifier                       = "${var.service}-${var.environment}-${count.index}"
  cluster_identifier               = aws_rds_cluster.default.id
  instance_class                   = var.instance_class
  engine                           = aws_rds_cluster.default.engine
  monitoring_role_arn              = var.monitoring_role
  engine_version                   = aws_rds_cluster.default.engine_version
  monitoring_interval              = var.monitoring_interval
  db_parameter_group_name          = var.regional_instance_param_group_name
  copy_tags_to_snapshot            = true
  publicly_accessible              = false
  db_subnet_group_name             = var.regional_subnet_group_name
}

resource "aws_rds_cluster_instance" "cluster_instances" {
  count                            = var.monitoring_interval = "0" ? var.cluster_instance_count : 0
  identifier                       = "${var.service}-${var.environment}-${count.index}"
  cluster_identifier               = aws_rds_cluster.default.id
  instance_class                   = var.instance_class
  engine                           = aws_rds_cluster.default.engine
  engine_version                   = aws_rds_cluster.default.engine_version
  db_parameter_group_name          = var.regional_instance_param_group_name
  copy_tags_to_snapshot            = true
  publicly_accessible              = false
  db_subnet_group_name             = var.regional_subnet_group_name
}
```

Line Reference:
[image]

Thanks for your help. Probably something small I'm just missing or misunderstood about terraform conditionals.

Comment: That's just some sort of basic syntax error. Which line in your main.tf is line `68`?

Comment: @MarkB   

count                            = var.monitoring_interval = "0" ? var.cluster_instance_count : 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're missing an `=` in your condition. Change it to this:

```
var.monitoring_interval == "0" ? var.cluster_instance_count : 0
```

Comment: FML,thanks. Let me try.